# calling an Action in the Controller through JQuery from the cshtml and returning a value back

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I have a cshtml page, with 3 text boxes and 3 dropdowns.

My idea is to have the user make a decision on the first question dropdown (YES/NO), and depending on this answer, populate the second text box, and enable the second dropdown (YES/NO), and same process for the third textbox.

I have the following at the moment:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    //disable the textboxes 
    $("#T_FirstQuestion").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#T_SecondQuestion").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#T_ThirdQuestion").attr('disabled', true);

    //and the dropdowns intially
    $("#SecondQuestYesNo").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#ThirdQuestYesNo").attr('disabled', true);

    $("#FirstQuestYesNo").change(function () {
        val = $("#FirstQuestYesNo").val();
        PostValue(val);

    });

    function PostValue(val) {
        var url = "/Home/DecisionFirstQuest";
        $("#T_SecondQuestion").attr('enabled', true);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: { value: val }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
    }


});

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Decision", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <font face="Arial" size="2"><b>1</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.TextBox("T_FirstQuestion", ViewData["T_FirstQuestion"], new { @class = "NormalTextBox" })
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DropDownList("FirstQuestYesNo", ViewData["FirstQuestYesNoData"] as SelectList, new { @class = "normalDropdowns" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <font face="Arial" size="2"><b>1</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.TextBox("T_SecondQuestion", ViewData["T_SecondQuestion"], new { @class = "NormalTextBox" })
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DropDownList("SecondQuestYesNo", ViewData["SecondQuestYesNoData"] as SelectList, new { @class = "normalDropdowns" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <font face="Arial" size="2"><b>1</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.TextBox("T_ThirdQuestion", ViewData["T_ThirdQuestion"], new { @class = "NormalTextBox" })
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DropDownList("ThirdQuestYesNo", ViewData["ThirdQuestYesNoData"] as SelectList, new { @class = "normalDropdowns" })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

and my Controller is as follows :-

```
        public ActionResult DecisionFirstQuest(string value)
    {
        string strMessage = "";

        if (value == "Yes")
        {
            strMessage = "You have chosen YES!";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = "You have chosen NO!";
        }

        ViewData["T_SecondQuestion"] = strMessage;

        return RedirectToAction("Decision");
    }

    public ActionResult DecisionSecondQuest(string value)
    {
        string strMessage = "";

        if (value == "Yes")
        {
            strMessage = "You have chosen YES!";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = "You have chosen NO!";
        }

        ViewData["T_ThirdQuestion"] = strMessage;

        return RedirectToAction("Decision");
    }

    public ActionResult Decision()
    {

        string FirstQuestYesNo = HttpContext.Request["FirstQuestYesNo"];

        ViewData["T_FirstQuestion"] = "First Question Text";

        var ddlYesNoData = new SelectList(new[]
                                      {
                                          new {ID="",Name="Please Select"},
                                          new {ID="Yes",Name="Yes"},
                                          new{ID="No",Name="No"},
                                      },
                        "ID", "Name", 1);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstQuestYesNo))
            ViewData["FirstQuestYesNoData"] = FirstQuestYesNo;
        else
            ViewData["FirstQuestYesNoData"] = "Yes";

        ViewData["FirstQuestYesNoData"] = ddlYesNoData;
        ViewData["SecondQuestYesNoData"] = ddlYesNoData;
        ViewData["ThirdQuestYesNoData"] = ddlYesNoData;



        return View();
    }
```

I am managing to get the value of the first dropdown, and redirecting to the Decision action, however I am not getting the second question textbox filled up. Also I am getting like a popup with some HTML code, which I would like to avoid.

So basically my question is, how can I fill up the second text box, and after the user chooses the (YES/NO), then fill up the third textbox.

Also, am I using the correct approach or is there a better way to do this using MVC?

Thanks for your help and time!

-------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------------
I decided to go for a more easy example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#YesNo").change(function () {
        val = $("#YesNo").val();
        var url = "../Home/Decision";
        $.post(url, { value: val});

    });



});

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Decision", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="Decision" }))
{

@Html.DropDownList("YesNo", new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Select", Value = "" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Yes", Value = "Yes" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="No", Value = "No" }
                     })

string FirstQuestText = ViewBag.FirstQuestData;

 @Html.TextBox("T_FirstQuestion", FirstQuestText, new { @class = "NormalTextBox" })   
}
```

And the Controller Actions:-

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Decision(string value)
    {
        string strMessage = "";
        if (value == "Yes")
        {
            strMessage = "This is the Second Yes Question";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = "This is the Second No Question";
        }

        ViewBag.FirstQuestData = strMessage;
        return View();
    }
```

The problem now is that I am getting the ViewBag.FirstQuestData populating correctly, however it is not displayed in the @Html.TextBox

-----------------------------------JSON UPDATE---------------------------------------
cshtml

```
        $("#YesNoQuest1").change(function () {
        alert('change');
        val = $("#YesNoQuest1").val();
        var url = "../Home/Decisions1";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
             alert(data.message);
        });
```

controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Decisions1(string value)
    {
        string strMessage = "";
        if (value == "Yes")
        {
            strMessage = "This is the Second Yes Question";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = "This is the Second No Question";
        }

        return Json(new { message = strMessage }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use JsonResult in your controller, instead of redirecting to actions? Your calls are ajax, you probably want to stick to returning JSON and interpreting that in your javascript.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do that?  Never used JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try returning string based data instead of Redirecting to Action as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Decision(string value)
{
    string strMessage = "";
    if (value == "Yes")
    {
        strMessage = "This is the Second Yes Question";
    }
    else
    {
        strMessage = "This is the Second No Question";
    }

    ViewBag.FirstQuestData = strMessage;
    return Content(strMessage); //No need to return complete View
}
```

You can receive this message in the Ajax post call as below:

```
    $("#YesNo").change(function () {
            val = $("#YesNo").val();
            var url = "../Home/Decision";
            $.post(url, { value: val},function(data){ 
                         alert(data);
                        //Here you can right your logic to manipulate data
           });
    });
```

Hope this helps:

------- UPDATE to Use JSON data -------------------
Here is controller to return Json:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult YourController() 
{ 
  //Do your Logic
  return Json(new { message = "Data" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

$.getJSON("../YourController", function(data) {
     alert(data.foo);
     alert(data.baz);
});
```

Comment: Cool this works! I can manipulate the data returned in the JQuery.  I will accept this question, however someone mentioned returning JSON, is it possible with this example?

Comment: I have edited my answer to return Json content from the Controller . please check once.

Comment: Damn .. wasted 10 minutes ... writing something similar :/

Comment: @Mohan the Json did not work.  return Json(new { message = strMessage}); and the JQUERY $.getJSON("../Home/Decisions1", function (data) {
            alert(data.message);
        });

Comment: @Johann - Are getting any error? is there any error displaying in your console log? Try Using return Json(new { message = "Data" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: I tried what you suggested but no luck.  I also tried with message = strMessage.  I am not getting anything back, the alert is not hit and I get [object: Object]

Comment: @Johann - Please try to show your code so that i can try to tell you why it's not working for you.

Comment: @Mohan, I added a JSON Update to my question.  Thanks

Comment: @Johann - I observed you have mentioned HttpPost for your controller which meant only for POST call.. getJosn method will call get based controller only not HttpPost. So mention HTTPGET for your controller and No need to use JsonResult as return type. Just use ActionResult only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17387/discussion-between-mohan-and-johann)

Comment: @Mohan, ok I did the changes as you suggested but still not working. I would think its the JQuery though, because the alert is not even hit, so the dropdown is not effective yet

Answer (score 2):

If you use "Json result" from returning a response from Controller to View, mention datatype as 'json' in the Ajax Setting as

```
function PostValue(val) {
        var url = "/Home/DecisionFirstQuest";
        $("#T_SecondQuestion").attr('enabled', true);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType:'json',
            data: { value: val }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
}
```

and you can fetch the result in your 'msg' object.

Note: Do not use getJSON() as it cache responses which may cause your data not in sync with your repository. But you can still use it by settinb cache = FALSE in ajax setting as follows:

$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

This line should precede your ajax call.

Thanks